# Lifetime extension of temporary object

Tags: c++, lifetime

There  is the following piece of code

```
void bar(int  const & x) //#3
{
}

void foo(int  const &  x) //#1
{    
    bar(x); //#2
}

int main()
{
   double  x = 1.0;
   foo(static_cast<int>(x)); //#0    
}
```

At #0 a prvalue is created and it is passed to foo #1.
The lifetime of object is extended. Then it is passed to bar #2. At this point the temporary object is not extended twice?

Sanitizer does report any issue.

What I am missing at this point?

Comment: Why would there be an lifetime extension at `#2`? `x` is not a prvalue... And even if a new temporary was created the variable it would be bound to would go out of scope at the end of the function call expression ending the duration the compiler needs to keep the object referred to alive for...

Comment: No lifetime extension is happening, the temporary `int` lives until the end of the full expression `#0`.

Comment: The point you're missing is that there is no extension; the temporary has its "natural" lifetime, which is until `foo` returns. `const int& y = static_cast<int>(x));` would be a lifetime extension.

Comment: what issue is reported? Please include the report verbatim in the question

Comment: In any case, lifetime of a temporary object is _never_ extended twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a temporary here:

```
foo(static_cast<int>(x)); //#0
```

The life-time of this temporary is until the end of this expression, which effectively means until `foo` returns here. Because `foo` calls `bar`, it doesn't return until `bar` does. Therefore, there is no need to extend the life-time anywhere here.